# how to remove a node in Json dict in python

Tags: python, json

I have a josn dict created in python like:

```
    {
    "ses_group": {
        "grp_a": "ratncib",
        "grp_b": "batric",
        "grp_c": {
            "grp_ca": "x",
            "grp_cb": "y"
        },
        "grp_d": {}
    }
}
```

expeted:

```
{
    "grp_a": "ratncib",
    "grp_b": "batric",
    "grp_c": {
        "grp_ca": "x",
        "grp_cb": "y"
    },
    "grp_d": {}
}
```

how can i acheive this in python/pyspark, above json is stored in dictionary datatype in pythoncode

Comment: Just get the value of the "ses_group" key?

Comment: If your dictionary is `d`, just `d = d["ses_group"]` - very little to do with pyspark, or python-jsons?

Comment: try : `dct['ses_group']`

Comment: whats pyspark to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

just like, get a bit into the dict. like you have a key, then just get the value-of = that key.

I mean, if you have a key named `k123g86x2nc&^52vbo].ll;123eld7=-*(93nchd73wefjvq0-1` for example, you can do just `mine_dict[f"k123g86x2nc&^52vbo].ll;123eld7=-*(93nchd73wefjvq0-1"]` and get the underlying value of that key, whatever it may be.

I might be wrong or missing something, but I think therein lies the solution that are you desiring in this particular case at least.